Theorem for networks that says that in a relatively compact space (or compact) we have an accumulation point for the network.
Definition.(Net) A net in a directed set $X$ is a function $P: \Lambda \to X$, where $\Lambda$ is a directed set.
Definition.(Relatively compact space) Given a topological space $X$, a subset $A \subseteq X$ is called relatively compact if the closure $\overline{A}$ is compact in $X$.
I would like to know if there is a theorem for networks that says that in a relatively compact space (or compact) we have an accumulation point for the network.
Something like:
given $(x_\alpha)_\alpha$ in the relatively compact (or compact) there is an $x_0$ (accumulation point or sticking point) such that for every $\alpha_0$ and every neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$, there exists an $\alpha\geq \alpha_0$ such that $x_\alpha$ belongs to $V$.
Here's the translation:
I know that for sequences this result is true, but for nets in general, is this also true?
I'd be grateful if anyone knows.

At least for compact sets, the result you are looking for is Theorem 17.4 from Willard's General Topology (Page 118).

For relatively compact sets, it isn't true for sequences, much less nets. You need full compactness for this (otherwise, the accumulation point can be on the boundary, but not in the set).
